# fnLengthChange Issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

For some reason only when I have the viewAll click function it stops the use of dataTables I don't know if its a syntax error or what. The only problem is I'm not getting a syntax error. So I don't know what the problem is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var oTable = $('#contentPagesPageList').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'rti<"pagination"p>',
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
} );

$('.viewAll').click(function() {
    oTable.fnLengthChange( -1 );   
)}; 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are passing a negative value to it i think: with that function you set the number of record to display and i haven't found anywhere that you can pass a negative number. if you want to display all you could use:

```
  oTable.fnLengthChange($('#contentPagesPageList tr').length);
```

EDIT - the problem was that fnLengthChange was not a standard function of the api and so you had to include it!This is the code to include:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnLengthChange = function ( oSettings, iDisplay )
{
    oSettings._iDisplayLength = iDisplay;
    oSettings.oApi._fnCalculateEnd( oSettings );

    /* If we have space to show extra rows (backing up from the end point - then do so */
    if ( oSettings._iDisplayEnd == oSettings.aiDisplay.length )
    {
        oSettings._iDisplayStart = oSettings._iDisplayEnd - oSettings._iDisplayLength;
        if ( oSettings._iDisplayStart < 0 )
        {
            oSettings._iDisplayStart = 0;
        }
    }

    if ( oSettings._iDisplayLength == -1 )
    {
        oSettings._iDisplayStart = 0;
    }

    oSettings.oApi._fnDraw( oSettings );

    $('select', oSettings.oFeatures.l).val( iDisplay );
}
```

And this is the code for your button:

```
$('.viewAll').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#contentPagesPageList tr').length);
    oTable.fnLengthChange($('#contentPagesPageList tr').length);
});
```

Comment: can you make an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: For some reason it won't even paginate for the jfiddle. But you can see how the lengthChange doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/hrfYA/

Comment: There is an error in your javascript file contentpages.js: you use:   )};  instead of });

Comment: When I run it on my site I get the oTable.fnLengthChange is not a function errror.

Comment: Now i got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/hrfYA/2/ i'll update the answer with the solution

Comment: For some odd reason I'm still getting the fnLengthChange is not a function errror.

Comment: I had put that function for the api in the jquery.dataTables.js file.Is that not what I"m supposed to do.

Comment: Actually if you put that function just at the end of the file you should have no problems, but in your original fiddle you had two separate datables.js files (i removed one) so maybe that was the problem!

Comment: Thank you. I got it working, however is there a way to make it take off the pagination and that Blue Button that makes you see ALL records have that button go to a different button that once clicked goes back to the paginated version.

Comment: Yes you can, you just call the same function with the pagination length you want to set: look here http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/hrfYA/3/ (it's just a start but it works)

Comment: One last thing buddy and I APPRECIATE ALL of your help on this. I've learned already from this. What happens to the it being a blue button when its clicked.

Comment: For some reason it removes the span and strong tags when we remove the class.

Comment: Now it works corretcly switching from displaying all results to paginating! :) http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/hrfYA/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/hrfYA/5/   for some reason on my actual page the paginate button won't work. But yet the button that goes to the view all does. Oddly enough in the jfiddle it won't work at all but on my site just the paginate button does not work where it takes ALL records paginates them.

Comment: On the fiddle you are missing a plugin: http://webstuffshare.com/demo/jConfirmAction/jconfirmaction.jquery.js after you install it you must use live('click', function()) and not click(function() to handle the event (line 75 and 82 of your script)

Comment: because i'm adding/removing classes and you need live() to attach handler to elements (or classes) that are added to the DOM after creation